# find malicious code scanning smb port

Tags: smb

The admin of my network said our server is trying to scan port 445. We use our server for two reasons. 
1. A web server, 
2. Gateway for our colleague's laptop.

How can I find the malicious code? How can I know whether it is running in our server?

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Mokubai, CentOs 7 is running on the server

Comment: That information should be in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the malicious process has bound to the port you might be able to identify said process with `netstat -ltnp | grep 445`.  From there you can use `ps ax | grep YOUR_PID` to map the process ID returned by the netstat to actual running code.

If that doesn't work for you then you could install [Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) (not a bad idea even if you weren't having the problems you are having) and let it figure out what keeps scanning that port.  FYI, port 445 is used by Samba, so focus on things related to file sharing to narrow down your issue quickly.